# Isomorphism in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let be $M$ a closed subespace of a Hilbert space ,$H$ .

Can we conclude that $M^ \perp $ and $H$/ $M$ are isometrically isomorphic?.

Comment: What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: I think it is true, but I don´t know how to prove it

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think there's a good guess as to the isomorphism, if there is one:
$$f : M^\perp \to H / M : x \mapsto x + M.$$
Certainly the map is linear (it's a restriction of the quotient map). To show it's injective, we have
$$f(x) = f(y) \implies x + M = y + M \implies x - y \in M.$$
However, since $x, y \in M^\perp$, a subspace, we have $x - y \in M \cap M^\perp = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Thus, $x = y$ and $f$ is injective.

To show surjectivity, we use the fact that $M \oplus M^\perp = H$. Then, given $x + M \in H/M$, we can express $y$ (uniquely) by $y = x + v$ for $v \in M$ and $x \in M^\perp$. Then
$$f(x) = x + M = (x + v) + M = y + M,$$
as required. Thus $f$ is a (vector space) isomorphism.

To show it's an isometry (and hence a normed linear space isomorphism), recall first the definition of the norm:
$$\|x + M\| = d_M(x) := \inf_{m \in M} \|x - m\|.$$
However, we know that $M^\perp = \operatorname{ker} P_M$, where $P_M$ is the orthogonal projection onto $M$. We also know that the orthogonal projection is the metric projection, meaning that $P_M(x)$ is the closest point to $x$ in $M$. Therefore, for all $x \in M^\perp$, the closest point to $x$ in $M$ is $0$, so,
$$\|x - 0\| = \inf_{m \in M} \|x - m\| = \|x + M\| = \|f(x)\|.$$
That is, $f$ is also an isometry.