# Quotient space and direct sum in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be Banach space and $X=Y\oplus Z$ (direct sum). Prove that the quotient space $X/Y$ is isomorphic to $Z$, $X/Y\cong Z$.

Proof. 
Let $[x_0]\in X/Y$, i.e. 
$[x_0]=\{x|\ x=x_0+y,\ y\in Y\}$. 
Since $x_0=y_0+z_0$, then we obtain 
$[x_0]=[z_0]$ and mapping $f:\ X/Y\mapsto Z$ defined as $f([x_0])=z_0$.

To show the equality of norms, we consider 
$\|[x_0]\|=\inf_Y \|x_0+Y\|=\inf_Y \|z_0+Y\|\leq \|z_0\|$.

I cannot figure out the spaces for which norms $\|[x_0]\|$ and $\|z_0\|$ are equivalent. Whether there is a criterion for how to choose $Z$ at which these norms are equal or, at least, equivalent.

Comment: This question is unclear. In the title you write "orthogonal complement" but you nowhere mention a Hilbert space. Do you mean that $X = H$ is Hilbert and $Y + Z$ is the direct sum composition of $H$ into a closed subspace and its orthogonal complement? If yes, then this question is possibly a duplicate to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493510/isomorphism-in-a-hilbert-space

Comment: @ Jan. Many thanks, I corrected the question. The norm-related issue remains unclear.

Comment: There's no reason why the infimum must be achieved at $y = 0$. For example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $Y = \langle (1,0) \rangle$ and $Z = \langle (1,1) \rangle$ the infimum of $\|(1,1) + y\|$ happens at $y = (-1,0)$. @Jan

Comment: @Trevor Gunn. Does your example show that there is no isomorphism? Maybe it is possible to modify the above mapping $f$ in order to obtain the isomorphism?

Comment: It shows that the norms aren't necessarily equal but it doesn't show that they can't be equivalent.

Comment: I think the correct approach here is to use the first isomorphism theorem: $X/\ker f \cong f(X)$ but necessary hypotheses for this are that $Y$ and $Z$ are closed.

Comment: So, the conclusion is $\|[x_0]\|\leq \|z_0\|$. The question remains: find Banach spaces for which $\|z_0\|\leq c\cdot\|[x_0]\|$ for some constant $c>0$ (and, thus, the norms are equivalent). And vice versa, for which Banach spaces no such constant exists.